# action throws custom exception but not caught in filter

Tags: java

I write my own exception class, and i have thrown this exception in my action class, i have a filter, my request handled by action after passed from the filter and if my action class thrown my own exception it is not caught in filter. Please let me know why this happening.

This is my filter

```
public class myfilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain)throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        try
        {   
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/"+url);
            if(rd != null)
            {   
                rd.forward(request,response);
            }   
        }
        catch(MyException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("filter caught exp--"+ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
        }   
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
    {
    }
    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("--filter destroy--");
    }
}
```

My struct action class is here

```
public class eventaction extends Action
{
    public ActionForward execute( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws MyException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        /*
            Statements
        */
        throw new MyException("exception");

    }
}
```

the following line logged with some traces

```
[14:50:22:480]|[07-04-2013]|[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[action]]|[SEVERE]|[12]|: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception|MyException: Unable_to_add_event
```

**if i caught genric exception in my filter not MyException, it caught by filter. Why?**

```
catch(Exception ex) //catch(MyException ex)
{
    System.out.println("filter caught exp--"+ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what this filter is for, but it seems like you are abusing the filter here for some kind of task... A filter is meant to be a removable component to add certain features to your application (like logging or authentication), but yours is either forwarding or throwing an exception. The next filter in the filter chain is never called (`chain.doFilter(...)`).

Comment: i am using this filter for url filtering, i didnt mention here my business logic......... and i dont have other filters after that this filter. so that i didnt use chain.doFilter.. k..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be wrapped into `ServletException` or similar.

You can see that printing class name of exception.

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName() + " filter caught exp--"+ex.getMessage());         
    throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**EDIT**

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    Throwable t = ex.getCause();
    if (t != null && t instanceOf MyException) {
        MyException m = (MyException) t;
        //handle your exception.

    } else {
        //handle other cases
    }
}
```

Comment: I put print as you suggest but here ex.getClass().getName is servletException... following is log.... refer this
 class--javax.servlet.ServletException--exp--com.MyException: Unable_to_add_event

Comment: that's what I'm telling. Wrapping any exception into Servlet Exception is a good practice here. So that you can handle any case by catching only ServletException

Comment: if i have to handle MyException, how to handle this.... because the exeption instance will be only a servlet exception its not instance of MyException.... K....

Comment: I already did by catch(MyException) {} catch(Exception){} for single try, here thrown exception from request dispatcher.forward caught in catch(Exception){} if i remove this i.e if i only use catch(MyException){} it doesn't caught and forward throws my exception to the error page that i mentioned in web.xml.. is this real behavior.. here i elaborated my scenario very deep

Comment: This mechanism of wrapping makes code scalable and more readable. You can throw anything, and everything you throw makes servlet work incorrect, thus different types of exceptions are hanled in unified way

Answer (score 0):

You are catching custom exception type while throwing `IOException` and `ServletException` here. 
If `try` block never throws `MyException` other than `ServletException` or `IOException` you may not able to catch that exception.

Read about `Exception hierarchy` from [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_hierarchy.shtml)

**Edit :** look at this diagram.

[image]

As you can see Exception is the supper type of Exceptions. So when you use `Catch(Exception e)` it will catch 
all types of Exceptions since it is a supper type. In your case your `MyException` belong the group where IO Exception in. If you want to catch `IOException` or  `ServletException` You have to use supper type of **NOT YOUR CUSTOM EXCEPTION.****

Comment: here i am using requestdispatcher this forwards to action that i mentioned. which throws MyException. my question is, it doesnt caught in filter, if i caught as Exception, it can caught... got it???

Comment: @aravind that's what I was telling. Look at my Edit part.

Comment: as you suggest if i caught as servlet exception, it can caught.. (i.e) request dispatcher only throws servlet exception.. ri8???

Comment: If you really want to catch ServletException from your MyException create Your MyException by extending ServletException

Comment: @aravind yes. IF you want to catch multiple exception type in one catch block you can do it too

Comment: I already did by catch(MyException) {} catch(Exception){} for single try, here thrown exception from request dispatcher.forward caught in catch(Exception){} if i remove this i.e if i only use catch(MyException){} it doesn't caught and forward throws my exception to the error page that i mentioned in web.xml.. is this real behavior.. 
here i elaborated my scenario very deep